# Unknown interpreted text role "setting" with Django docstring and Sphinx

Tags: django, python-sphinx

I'm documenting a **Djagno 2.2** application.

The [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-documentation/#guidelines-for-restructuredtext-files) states linking to the settings as

```
Add :mod:`django.contrib.auth` to your :setting:`INSTALLED_APPS`...
```

In my documentation, The statement is

```
The length is defined in the :setting:`URL_ID_LENGTH`
```

When generating the documentation using **Sphinx**

```
make html
```

Gives **WARNING**

```
:docstring of app.models.Class.function:4: WARNING: Unknown interpreted text role "setting".
```

I have `sphinx.ext.intersphinx` added to the `conf.py` of **Sphinx**.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-documentation/#django-specific-markup), it has its own specific markup.

You will need to add `djangodocs` from Django's [conf.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/docs/conf.py#L40) into yours:

```
extensions = [
    "djangodocs",
    'sphinx.ext.extlinks',
    "sphinx.ext.intersphinx",
    "sphinx.ext.viewcode",
]
```

Then place the [`djangodocs` extension file](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/docs/_ext/djangodocs.py#L26-L31) into your `docs/_ext/djangodocs.py`.

And finally [import its path](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/docs/conf.py#L30) with something like this:

```
sys.path.append(abspath(join(dirname(__file__), "_ext")))
```

Comment: Is it explained in the Django documentation that there is a Sphinx extension called "djangodocs"?

Comment: No, it merely states that it has its own specific markup, including `:setting:`. I assumed it was a custom role defined somewhere in their `conf.py`, but found it is their own extension.

Comment: Django has documentation regarding Django specific markup. But nothing about how to use it. They should have it in the documentation itself.

Comment: That issue was resolved very quickly as "invalid". The problem remains that there is no documentation explaining that you need to enable the "djangodocs" extension in order to use the Django-specific markup.

Comment: I guess they assume that developers will "just know" about it when writing their own add-ons/extensions/etc. for Django. :/ I'd encourage @AnujTBE to elaborate why this is an issue for developers who write documentation.